# What exactly is isObject testing for?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

It doesn't appear to be abstract objects or object literals.

I tested [isObject() from underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1007) with the following values:

```
var falsy = [
        false,
        '', "",
        0, -0,
        undefined, null,
        NaN
    ],
    // 6 truthy
    truthy = [
        true,
        'hello',
        -1, 1,
        Infinity,
        /test/
    ],
    // 3 lengthy
    lengthy = [
        function () {
            return undefined;
        },
        "string",
        [0]
    ],
    // 8 globals
    globals = [
        new String(),
        new Number(),
        new Boolean(),
        new Array(),
        new Object(),
        new Function(),
        new Date(),
        new RegExp()
    ],
    all = falsy.concat(truthy, lengthy, globals),
```

I used all.

This is what I got back from the console.

[image]

The one I found the most odd was that a string was not detected as an object thought it is clearly not a basic/primitive type and can hold properties.

This seems like a flimsy implementation of `isObject()`.

What if fact is this thing doing?

Comment: Can you be clearer ? What's exactly the string which was not detected as an object ? For your information "somestring" is **not** an object.

Comment: I provided input and output, you can see that strings are not detected.

Comment: `new String()` is an object. `"this one"` isn't.

Comment: [Distinction between string primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects)

Comment: Disregarding the false premise, it wouldn't be practical in most real life situations to consider strings as objects.

Comment: @dstroy - strings are objects in Java, that's what threw me off.  So back to the question - what is this used for, it's only used once in underscore for `_.clone()` "in_java_i_am_an_object"

Comment: but yep, from crockford .... `JavaScript contains a small set of data types. It has the three primitive types boolean, number, and string and the special values null and undefined. Everything else is variations on the object type.`

Comment: Except for null and undefined, there are constructors for Boolean, Number, and String. So they can be objects or primitives. When an attempt is made to reference them as objects they will be automatically promoted to objects via their constructors (and I believe demoted back to primitives when the operation is done, but I'm not sure so don't quote me on that). As to undefined and null, they are both primitive values but for historical reasons there is also a global variable `undefined` that has the value of undefined but in non-strict ES5 and older JS versions you can assign anything to it.

Comment: all falsy values are not objects

Comment: just coincidental it seems.

Answer (score 0):

It does in fact just return `true` for `Objects` and `false` for `primitives`.

Javascript has [5 primitives](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/):

```
undefined, null, boolean, string and number
```

However, the language also has Object versions of some of these primitives eg String, Number. So `"foo"` is a primitive but `new String("bar")` is an object.

The difference between primitives and objects is often hidden by the fact that javascript uses coercion to automatically convert primitives into objects and to convert objects into primitives when necessary.